# How to rearrange equation to cubic polynomial form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, factoring

**Summarize the problem**

I have these 2 equations and i need a cubic polynomial in terms of Z so i can run numerical routines on it. How can i be sure that's possible to factor that way and second how can i do it?

For this particular case i know the answer but i don't know how to get there.
$$
P=\frac{R*T}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v²} (1)
$$

$$
v=\frac{Z*R*T}{P} (2)
$$

**Provide details and any research**

So i Plug (2) into (1).
and my goal is to arrive at (az³+bz²+cz+d=0).
I know the solution in this case to be

$$
0 = z³-(\frac{bP}{RT}+1)z²+(\frac{aP}{(RT)²})z-\frac{abP²}{(RT)³}(3)
$$
**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

Since i'm trying to solve the equation numerically, i first tried to make MATLAB do the work for me and simplify it but i had no success.
I tried by hand but no luck either.

Comment: "*So i Plug (2) into (1)*" ...and what do you get, which doesn't match the expected result? To make the calculations easier, you could eliminate the denominators first, then multiply by $P^2$ to make it a cubic equation in $(Pv)$, then substitute $Pv=ZRT$.

Comment: Perfect!! The tips you gave to make the calculations easier helped alot!

Comment: i was trying to code the steps in a generic way so i can always get equations in the cubic form, but i guess i have to work it one by one?

Comment: You can always eliminate $v$ between the equations by direct substitution, and get the cubic in $Z$. My previous comment was just about how to simplify the calculations when you do it by hand.